# ASP.NET event stub not created as expected in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have written an ASP.NET web user control with several other controls in it.  Whenever I try to assign an event to a control using the form designer, Visual Studio gives an hourglass for a moment, then does **not** add the event handler stub.

I can manually add the event handler code and edit the HTML to tie it together, but does anyone know what might cause this behavior?

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 on Win7 64bit.

The steps I follow are:

1 - Right-click on a checkbox control and choose "Properties"

2 - Go to the "events" area of the Properties sheet (the lightning bolt)

3 - Double-click on the "CheckedChanged" event

Result: Nothing

I should also note that the event drop down list for the CheckedChanged event is empty.

In response to some of the comments:

1 - The "codebehind" attribute is set in my .ascx file:

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Filename.ascx.vb" Inherits="NameSpace.ClassName" %>
```

2 - I have restarted Visual Studio and my pc with the same results.

Comment: This might not be it, but I know VS will struggle with Intellisense if the `Codebehind` attribute isn't set on the Page of the ASP/CX.

Comment: Sorry to state the obvious, but have you tried restarting VS and/or the PC yet?

Comment: I see this alot but usually restarting VS fixes it.  If not restarting the PC Always has... Also I have seen this when i was in debug mode but did not realize it.  The markup will get the event markup added but no error about being in debug mode or change to the codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem myself.

It turns out that I had manually edited the ".designer.vb" file to put it in a custom namespace, but I had not done the same thing to my code-behind file.

The .designer.vb file implements a partial class with declarations for all of the controls on the page.

The code-behind file completes that partial class, but since they were technically in different namespaces, the .vb file didn't see the other "part" of the partial class.