# Why don't auto generated events for a "Web User Control" create the EventHandler arguments in the code behind for an aspx page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, ascx, webusercontrol

I am using

- Visual Studio 2012
- .NET Framework 4.5
- Visual Basic 2012 (VB 11.0)

I have the web user control ascx page: MyControl.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="MyControl.ascx.vb" Inherits="MyControl" %>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="MyButton" OnClick="MyButton_Click" />
```

I have a web user control code behind: MyControl.ascx.vb

```
Public Class MyControl
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    Public Event MyClick As EventHandler

    Protected Sub MyButton_Click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles MyButton.Click
        RaiseEvent MyClick(sender, e)  
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then I have a page which consumes the user control: MyPage.aspx

```
<%@ Register Src="UserControls/MyControl.ascx" TagPrefix="ucMyControl" TagName="MyControl" %>
<div>
    <ucMyControl:MyControl runat="server" ID="UcMyControl" OnMyClick="UcMyControl_MyClick" />
</div>
```

When I select `<Create New Event>` from the intellesence as shown in the picture below
[image]

The generated `UcMyControl_MyClick` does not contain the `sender as Object, e as EventArgs` parameters. See below:

```
Protected Sub UcMyControl_MyClick()
End Sub
```

What I ***expect*** is to have the EventHandler arguments created whith the event like this:

```
Protected Sub UcMyControl_MyClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
End Sub
```

I am new to ASP.NET and Web User Controls. I have searched extensively for this issue to no avail. I have done the following in the MyControl.ascx.vb file

**1.**

```
Public Delegate Sub MyControlEventHandler(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)
Public Event MyClick as MyControlEventHandler
```

**2.**

```
Public Event MyClick as EventHandler(Of EventArgs)
```

**3.**

```
Public Event MyClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
```

**Related**

1. [ASP.NET event stub not created as expected in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099735/asp-net-event-stub-not-created-as-expected-in-visual-studio)
2. [Automatically create handler signature in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37077865/automatically-create-handler-signature-in-visual-studio)

Comment: You can after creating the event stub (crete new even) manually add the two parms. Eg somthing like this: Protected Sub WebUserControl1_MyClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs). However, your question still stands - how/why does  not the create new event not add these 2 parameters for you. As noted, AFTER you "create new event", the stub does appear, and if iyou add manually the 2 parms, they do work.

Comment: Why are you using 2012? Could just be a bug, it's pretty old.

Comment: @Albert D. Kallal, Yes when I manually add the parameters the events work.

Comment: @Nikki9696, I'm using 2012 because it is what is available for production code, when I open the solution with Visual Studio 2019 the same issue occurs--So I don't think it is a bug

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37077865/automatically-create-handler-signature-in-visual-studio

Comment: I used 2019 - and the issue exists - it not bug or version related.  One should be able to declare the 2 parmas in the public events stub - it just no one here has high enough pay grade and not really learned how to use asp.net. - I up-voted this question, as I would also like to know the answer.

Comment: @Nikki9696, that post appears to be related, if not, the exact issue I am having , however; it doesn't seem like there is a definitive solution. If that post ever gets an answer I hope it will translate to VB or Visual Studio 2012 whatever the issue may be. Regardless, that post opened up some avenues worth considering, thanks.

Comment: as noted - same issue in 2019. The solution right now is of course to manually edit the code stub after its been created - that does work.