Create New Events not autopopulating in Visual Studios
I know this may be a dumb question but my IntelliSense is working but not event arguments aren't auto populating. I took a screenshot of someone else's working to better explain. Not sure where to find the controls for this and google searching hasn't been fruitful. So the top picture is what should populate the bottom is what it is doing now which is nothing.



Unfortunately that did not resolve the issue but thanks for the suggestion.

What is the top most line of your aspx file?

<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="RadGridEditCustomValidatorVB.aspx.vb" Inherits="RadGridEditCustomValidatorVB" %>

Have you confirmed the name of the file you want to get the event handler from is called RadGridEditCustomValidatorVB.aspx.vb? And that the class is called RadGridEditCustomValidatorVB? Please add the declaration of the class and the event handler you are trying to consume. Also, please update the tags on your post to include asp.net and vb.net

Is the MyControl is a type of button? I created a Button and event arguments auto pupulate like this. Could you share  a sample to help us better understand this scenario?

Related?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67694005/why-dont-auto-generated-events-for-a-web-user-control-create-the-eventhandler

@ClearlyClueless  Sorry for the delay but here it is Partial Class RadGridEditCustomValidatorVB. The item I had made which works  was within :
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" Width="800px" OnDeleteCommand="RadGrid_ItemDeleted" > its just I had to write out the code instead of it autogenerating but hoping to fix for future projects.

Did you install any  third-party extensions? If yes, please try to disable them  from VS > Extensions > Manage Extensions > Installed. If this issue still persists, please also try to reset VS settings
